# Ouput json to http.ResponseWriter with template

Tags: json, http, go, go-templates

i've this template:

```
var ListTemplate = `
{
    "resources": [
        {{ StringsJoin . ", " }}
    ]
  }
`
```

rendered with:

```
JoinFunc := template.FuncMap{"StringsJoin": strings.Join}
tmpl := template.Must(template.New("").Funcs(JoinFunc).Parse(ListTemplate))
```

if i send it to a http.ResponseWriter the output text is escaped.

```
var list []string
tmpl.Execute(w, list)
```

how can i write a json this way?

Comment: Why not serialise to JSON properly? What is the reason to manually craft it from pieces?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't use Go's template engine (neither [`text/template`](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/) nor [`html/template`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/)) to generate JSON output, as the template engine has no knowledge of JSON syntax and rules (escaping).

Instead use the [`encoding/json`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) package to generate JSON. You may use [`json.Encoder`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Encoder) to write / stream the response directly to an [`io.Writer`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Writer), such as [`http.ResponseWriter`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ResponseWriter).

Example:

```
type Output struct {
    Resources []string `json:"resources"`
}

obj := Output{
    Resources: []string{"r1", "r2"},
}

enc := json.NewEncoder(w)

if err := enc.Encode(obj); err != nil {
    // Handle error
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

Outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/JX3JNCMZUxq)):

```
{"resources":["r1","r2"]}
```

Comment: thanks, i definitively should do this way. the application is a very simple apl that was not meant to return json at the beginning, just a raw text

Comment: is it okay to `json.NewEncoder(w)` for every new request?